# Unreliable parallel loop fails 4 out of 400 times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing

I have a Parallel foreach function that creates a new instance of a class, that manipulates a picture, and saves it to the disk...

However approximately 4 times out of 400, the picture gets saved to the disk, but without being manipulated, my theory is that when it happens, some of the propperties existing in my class is null, when they are not suppost to...

The 4 (sometimes 3) errors mostly occurs in the first 10 images of the parallel loop.

There is no error message, it justs skip some of my code, for some reason... My breakpoint doesn't work when it is parralel, so it is hard to debug.

Any advice on how to proceed / debug / fix ?

**The code as requested**

```
    private static void GenerateIcons(Effects effect)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Icons\Original\"));

        FileInfo[] ff = dir.GetFiles();

        string mappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Icons\");

        List<string> paths = new List<string>();

        string ids = GetAllEffectIds(effect.TinyUrlCode);

        Parallel.ForEach(ff, item =>
        {
            if (!File.Exists(mappath + @"Generated\" + ids + "-" + item.Name))
            {
                paths.Add(mappath + @"Generated\" + ids + "-" + item.Name);
                ApplyEffects f = new ApplyEffects(effect, item.Name, mappath);
                f.SaveIcon();


            }
        });
        //Zip icons!
        ZipFiles(paths, effect.TinyUrlCode, ids, effect.General.Prefix);

    }
```

Comment: I would change line 4 of the code and that should fix it.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, personally I would do this at line 400. Line 4 looks correct to me :-)

Comment: @ChaosPandion Haha xD, But it's empty!

Comment: Ill update it with some code :p

Comment: @BjarkeCK, what/who's empty? The jar? Come on dude, ask a real question before this one gets closed.

Comment: does it work with a non-parallel foreach ?

Comment: I don't like the un-synchronized list access. Could be the culprit we are looking for.

Comment: [How to stop or break from a Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx)

Comment: @ChaosPandion What does it mean that my list access is un-synchronized?

Comment: @BjarkeCK Your ApplyEffects class (change that name BTW, it sounds like a method and it's very confusing... 'IconEffects' might be more suited. Think of it as: classes *are* something, methods *do* something) contains non-thread safe code you'll have to check out.

Comment: @BjarkeCK - Essentially if two threads try and add an item to the list at the same time any number of weird things could happen, like 4 items appearing to be missing from the resulting list.

Comment: @Alex, thank you, i can see why IconEffects is a better name. I'm considering just doing a regular Foreach Loop that takes all of the non-manipulated files and rendering them again. But ill experiment a bit more with the lock function thingy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write it in a more functional style, to hopefully remove the threading issues:

```
private static void GenerateIcons(Effects effect)
{
    var dir     = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Icons\Original\"));
    var mappath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Icons\");
    var ids     = GetAllEffectIds(effect.TinyUrlCode);

    var filesToProcess = dir
        .EnumerateFiles()
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(f => new { info = f, generated = File.Exists(mappath + @"Generated\" + ids + "-" + f.Name) })
        .ToList();

    Parallel.ForEach(filesToProcess.Where(f => !f.generated), file =>
    {
        new ApplyEffects(effect, file.info.Name, mappath).SaveIcon();
    });

    //Zip icons!
    ZipFiles(filesToProcess.Select(f => f.info), effect.TinyUrlCode, ids, effect.General.Prefix);
}
```

Comment: Wow, a learn a lot of other things here :) But this code actually increesed the number of errors to 40 or so... If i lock effect, and wrap it around everything in the parralel, it gives no errors, but then it's as slow as a non parallel foreach loop.

Comment: What does "apply effects" do?

Comment: It puts on, dropshadow, innershadow, gradient, stroke, and stuff like that. It contains a bunch of methods, wich all access two or three properties of ApplyEffects.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's the "effect" object that's not threadsafe - as this object will be being accessed by all the threads running at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, i have tried locking diffrent sections of code in there. But with no luck :(

Comment: I think i'll make a regular foreach loop after the parallel loop, and make that correct the wrongs. Hate the solution, but i can't see any other.

Comment: Can you create a new "effect" object inside each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that your list of paths is not being updated properly due to `List<T>` not being thread safe. Essentially if two threads try and add an item to the list at the same time any number of weird things could happen, like 4 items missing from the resulting list. Try using the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

```
Parallel.ForEach(ff, item =>
{
    if (!File.Exists(mappath + @"Generated\" + ids + "-" + item.Name))
    {
        lock(paths) 
        {
            paths.Add(mappath + @"Generated\" + ids + "-" + item.Name);
        }
        ApplyEffects f = new ApplyEffects(effect, item.Name, mappath);
        f.SaveIcon();
    }
});
```

Comment: The lock(paths) did not work unfortunately, but i am investigating the code in ApplyEffects to see if there is any code that is not thread safe. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @BjarkeCK - Despite this not being a solution you should definitely familiarize yourself with thread-safe collections.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked with the none parallel version?
2. Are you using any
   API functions that is not marked as thread safe?

To answer 1), mutex lock the entire function and test for errors.

To answer 2) reduce the amount of code in the mutex until you find the offending function. You can do this by bisection.

`ConcurrentBag<T>` Is a thread safe container.

Comment: Thank you for you awencer will study it closer now, And yes, it dos work with a non parallel version... Quick question, thread safe?

Comment: Functions that access the same data from different threads can be not thread safe if they don't have the appropriate mutex locks. See http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex